# Apache htaccess for generic pretty URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been crazy trying to make my .htaccess work, and followed several examples with no success (of course modifying them because they were mostly static).

My problem, is that I need a generic htaccess to redirect to random php files (omiting the php extension), for example:

- /xxxxx/     loads /xxxxx.php
- /yyyyy/zz   loads /yyyyy.php?param=zz

This is what I am trying with not success:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MYDOMAIN [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://MYDOMAIN/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$               /$1.php             [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?(.+)$           /$1.php?param=$2    [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

The problem is that I am getting 500 server error on any request.
If I comment the last rule, then:

- /xxxx works correctly
- /xxxx/ works correctly
- /xxxx/yyyy does not work correctly (it is not rewriting the wanted
  parameter).

Any help will be appreciated as I don't really know what is happening here.

P.S. I also tested to put a "stopping" rule in the beginning like:

```
RewriteRule ^.*\.php.*$ - [L]
```

And then I can have both rules without a 500 server error, just having a 404 in the parameters case.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 500 because your last rule is running without any conditions and causing infinite looping.

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/])/?$ $1.php?param=$2 [QSA,L]
```